# Каким образом очистить память?

Tags: c, память, valgrind

Есть две функции, одна используется в другой, как грамотно очистить память в первой, так чтобы вторая правильно работала?

```
// добавление символа к строке
void add_char(string_t *str, char c) {
    str->s[str->size++] = c;

    if (str->size >= str->capacity) {
        str->capacity *= 2;
        str->s = (char *) realloc(str->s, str->capacity * sizeof(char));
    }

    str->s[str->size] = '\0';
}
```

и

```
string_t concat_string(string_t s1, string_t s2) {
    string_t s = copy_string(s1); // копируем первую строку

    // добавляем символы второй строки
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.size; i++)
        add_char(&s, s2.s[i]);

    return s; // возвращаем строку
}
```

Простой free в конце первой функции "ломает" вторую

Comment: memset(str, 0, str->size)

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "очистить"? Освободить, судя по упоминанию `free`?